# Are atomic operations are only needed during multithreading?

Tags: multithreading, process, atomic

Are atomic operations only exists to provide thread safety .Do they play any role in when multiple single threaded processes are running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your OS, APIs, and programming language support it, atomic operations can be useful on memory that is mapped between the processes.  You can build locks shared between processes, etc.

EDIT: also signal handling.  It is as if your signal handler ran on a different thread than the rest of your code (whether it really does or not).  If you want to communicate between your signal handler and the rest of your code, you could use atomic operations on some global variables.

But assuming you are not doing interprocess memory mapping, or signal handling, then no?

Comment: Another example might be a platform where they were useful for code that might get interrupted by a signal.

Comment: ah. I knew there was another case!